# Better way for choosing next best max id for a shard

Tags: mysql, rds

I have a use case for range based shard in mysql i.e

```
---------------------
shard   | upperbound
---------------------
1       | 500
2       | 1000
3       | 1500
```

Meaning `Shard1` has `1- 500` users and `shard2` has `501-1000` users and so on. So that latter point on user base grow, will keep on adding new shards.

The user table looks like below:

```
-----------------------------
id   | name | email | contact
-----------------------------
1    |Test  |t@t.com|xxxxx
501  |Test1 |t@t.com|xxxxx
101  |Test2 |t@t.com|xxxxx
1001 |Test3 |t@t.com|xxxxx
```

So user with name `Test` resides in `shard1`, user with name `test2` resides in `shard2` and user with name `Test3` resides in `shard3` and so on.

When a new user registration happens, Based on the `open shards` lets say (Shard4 and Shard5 is open for registration) then it first does a `select on the user  table with range` to get the `next max possible Id` and increment by 1 and stores it. Problem with this approach is when two different people tries to register and from code `select` returns same id for the two different people/thread as both the user registration can't be in same transaction.

Is there any other better way for choosing the `next id for a shard using range` ?

Comment: As an option you can use SP (Stored procedure) for this without selecting and Inserting. Sp will do it and return the id.

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka: How SP will be aware of which shard it will go, I mean which range to look after, also how it will handle shard full? I am poor in mysql, any sample reference really helps

Comment: The probability of your problem is vastly reduced, if you can make sure that there is virtually *no time* between pulling the max Id and storing the new incremented one. You can make sure of that by either using an SP or sending the `select` and `insert` statemets *directly* after one another.

Comment: @cars10: Thats correct currently I am doing that way SELECT and INSERT just after checking incremented shard range. Still app is spread across multiple servers, still I am facing inconsistency problem. Could you please give some details regarding SP(way to consider the range also along with other data), that looks another way

Comment: OK, as the app runs on several servers you cannot securely exclude the possibility of the same id being pulled at two different sites, if you just follow my suggestion. Even if you have frequent replication between the instances in place, this can still happen. But what about assigning "local" shards to your various servers (each server has a number of their *own* shards)? That way you can reduce your synchronisation problem to each individual server.

Comment: To shard by id is an unflexible design, e.g you could not change your shard size or move a user to a different shard (although I don't know what your shards represent so it might not be relevant). An alternative (that would "by coincident" also solve your current problem) could be to add a second column with a shard number that defines the shard, and leave the id an autoincrement value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(id) from t for update
```

Should hold the lock on the max id till the transaction completes.